# Could Korean language SE have the dark theme?

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow has the dark theme, which you can opt in. It’d be nice if I could have it on Korean language SE, too. The light theme is too bright for me.

Comment: shall we ask this on the SE meta site instead? It will probably get more visibility with the SE staff over there

Comment: I got in touch with one of the staff at stackoverflow, this is what he had to say "*I took a look at the request. Unfortunately, we currently do not have plans to bring dark mode to other sites. Creating dark mode is actually quite a bit of work so it isn't as simple as turning it on :(*". Looks like they can't implement it here at the moment, sorry about that